# WordPress Parent Theme Styles not Loading in Child Theme unless enqueued

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently working on converting a HTML Website into WordPress. The problem is the client needs a Blog page which should use a theme he has purchased from ThemeForest. So basically I have to combine 2 completely different themes into 1. What I did is made the Theme from ThemeForest the Parent Theme and created a child theme and customized it as per the client's HTML Website.

The issue I'm facing is with the Blog page, in this page only the content area should be from the Parent Theme rest of it is from the child theme. Basically the problem is the stylesheets and scripts from the parent theme aren't loading until I enqueue them in the Child THeme's functions.php file. Any idea why this is happening?

Child Theme style.css

```
/*

Theme Name: TAA Theme

Template: blogist

*/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

You have to import parent theme style into child theme by using enqueue_function.

Check the Link. Wordpress follows the process to include parent theme stylesheet.

Comment: I was under the assumption that the Parent theme styles were automatically implemented with the Stylesheet Template: blogist code in the child theme but even when the parent theme stylesheet wasn't enqueued it was effecting the child theme's layout, I had to overwrite the child theme stylesheet codes with things like #content TARGET ELEMENT {}. Any idea of why this was happening?